# Visual Studio 2013 missing CLR Widows Form application template

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I was very surprise when I Tried to create Visual C++ Windows Form Application (CLR) in Visual Studio 2013 RC ultimate. I could not found any template for Windows form under CLR section. It was in Visual Studio 2010. 
 I tried by using "CLR Empty Project" but by adding any windows form it got error.

> Error 1   error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a [breaking change from VS2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.110).aspx).

As it says on the above MSDN page, under **Breaking Changes in Visual C++**:

> #### Integrated Development Environment
>
> - The following project templates no longer exist:
>
>   - Windows Forms Application
>   - Windows Forms Control Library
> - Although we recommend that you do not create Windows Forms applications in C++/CLI, maintenance of existing C++/CLI UI applications is supported. If you have to create a Windows Forms application, or any other .NET UI application, use C# or Visual Basic. Use C++/CLI for interoperability purposes only.

<sup>[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yteCK.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for answer. But can you tell any solution or alternative for this. I really need to use Windows Forms in C++

Comment: @imrankhalil well there's only two ways really: either create the apps initially in VS2010, then upgrade to VS2012 for maintenance, or use C# Forms for the GUI and a C++/CLI assembly for the real work. I would favour the second approach.

Comment: I Finally got a solution from here. I tried and its working for me. [http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php) Thanks for help.

Comment: A bit late - you could move to VS2015 but be warned - C++/CLI winforms is in German.  It is like that all the way up to VS2019.

Answer (score 5):

Follow below steps for VC++ 2013:

Step-1: File -> New -> Project -> Templates -> Visual C++ -> CLR -> CLR Console Application -> OK -> Finish

Step-2: Right-Click on Source Files -> Add new Item -> Visual C++ -> UI ->   Windows Forms (MyForm.h) -> Add

Step-3: Click on properties in top-right corner (or) Execute. Done!